# FragmentTransaction.add()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem with the add() method which is the method cannot read the arguments It can't read my BlankFragment class as a Fragment instead it reads the package name followed by the class name that's my code

```
package com.example.ucon.myapplication;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null){
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            BlankFragment firstFragment = new BlankFragment();
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant run the app with this error so .. logcat is still empty

Comment: Then the console messages will contain the error , I have no Idea what the error is actually

Comment: I solved the problem I had to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of android.app.Fragment in the fragment class thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Then add the answer to your question and mark it as correct answer ;)

Comment: I added an answer but cant accept it .. must wait 2 days

Comment: you can , click on the small tick under the vote counter

Comment: Thats what I did .. tells me to wait 2 days to accept my own answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem I had to import

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

instead of

```
android.app.Fragment
```

in the fragment class